# Heroku-Django: requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is not so much of a problem but I have been adding requirements.txt everytime I start a new project and deploy it on heroku. I don't understand the purpose of requirements.txt though and why it is so important.

Comment: It's list of all requirements of project! it's important because later you should now what did you used in this project.

Comment: and where should it be located inside a django project?

Comment: in project root path

Comment: Another question while I am at it, can you runserver (python3 manage.py runserver) after you deployed your project on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the scenario where u have installed 2 or 3 packages during the development cycle of 1/2 months.
During deployment, you forget to install one of them explicitly. At this time requirements.txt will come very handy.
So whenever you install a new package make sure add that package name in requirements.txt
And during deployment just running a single command like

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Will install all dependencies of your project.
And also useful when you clone the repo in new location.